# The best way to check the conditions

Tags: php, conditional-statements

The best way to check the conditions and what is difference between them?

This is my usual way:

```
if ($this->_is_valid_number() == TRUE) {
    //do some thing...
}
```

I've seen some code written in this way(for example):

```
if (TRUE == $this->_is_valid_number()) {
    //do some thing...
}
```

Are these different from each other? Which method is standard?

Comment: 1st one is recommended.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above, really.

`== true` is redundant with `if(condition)` so it could just be written as `if ($this->_is_valid_number())` which is pretty standard. If you want to check for false, you would do `if (!$this->_is_valid_number())` and if you would check for any other condition, you usually write like you would speak:

If my number is not one -> `if($number !== 1)`

Notice: Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp) article for difference between `==` and `===` operators

Comment: Don't forget to explain `==` vs `===` and to read the manual as some functions may falsely return values that will test true or false if not specifically tested for `===`.

Comment: Approved the edit by MorganFreeFarm, he just linked to another SO post there ;)

Comment: No worries! :)  ~Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The second method has a added benefit of failing if it's used incorrect.
The second one sets true to $number and creates no error, which is what the code should do but not what the coder is expecting.
Do it the other way around and it will fail

```
$number =5;

if($number == true) echo "true"; // true

if($number = true) echo "true"; //true 

if(true == $number) echo "true"; // true

if(true = $number) echo "true"; // fails
```

https://3v4l.org/suF9s